# Generated SHA256 Hash isn't working for PKCE OAuth2

Tags: javascript, hash, oauth-2.0, expo, sha256

I am trying to implement PKCE auth flow with oauth2.

here is what i am doing:

1. Generate random string.
2. Hash with SHA256 using expo-crypto and then base64encode.
3. proceed with login process.

after doing this i get an error stating the code challenge is incorrect.

https://tonyxu-io.github.io/pkce-generator/

after using this github generator (that uses cryptoJS), i am able to successfully login using the given values. If i hash the same string using both my generator and the github one it produces different results. if i use another online hash generator it will yield the same results as my generator. What is this github version doing different and how can i achieve this? i have looked at the source code and copied what i can except for the different crypto libraries.

i am using:

`Crypto.digestStringAsync(Crypto.CryptoDigestAlgorithm.SHA256, string)`

over the github examples:

`CryptoJS.SHA256(string)`

any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Ever figure this out? Having the EXACT same issue